# Invoke Task Method in an MVC Action but current Thread be Locked

Tags: task, deadlock

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {   
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var t1= Test1().Result;
            return View();
        }

        private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Test1()
        {
            string strUrl = "http://localhost:52033/api/values";
            var instanceClient = new HttpClient();
            var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, strUrl);
            var httpRespons = await instanceClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            return httpRespons;
        }
    }
```

When I was in the Index Action called Test1 (). The Result; Will happen when the current thread deadlock program has been no response, do not bring the Result calls suffixes can normal operation!

Comment: In short, what do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `Result` or `Wait` in an ASP.NET context; one reason is that it could cause deadlocks, [as I explain on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Instead, you should use `await`, like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var t1 = await Test1();
    return View();
}
```